# can't login to arch permission denied

Tags: arch-linux, tty, pam

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to login to linux from a tty or ly it says "permission denied" and prompt me to enter credentials again, even with root account I'm getting the same error ,

before the reboot I've been trying to get gnome-keyring to work so I have edited the
/etc/pam.d/login as this [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring)
said

any ideas on how to log in , i am on arch

Comment: "I'm getting the same error": which error???

Comment: my bad , it says "permission denied", I have edited the question

Comment: well, i have fixed that by reverting changes of pam.d/login (grom a live distro) , it seems that editing pam.d/login caused the issue,

Comment: When making changes to the system, always have a completely separate session (`Ctrl-Alt-F4`) logged in, and if you're changing anything major, already running as `root` (`sudo bash`). Switch back to your other (GUI) screen, and continue. If your computer is shared, this is a horrible security hole. Physical Security!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the changes made in `/etc/pam.d/login`
were faulty or in the incorrect order. 
This causes your authentication sequence provided by [pam.d](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d) to fail.

A possible solution:

1. Boot into your computer using a live ISO.
2. Mount the partition the system is installed on (the root).:

   ```
   mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
3. Then you would want to edit `/etc/pam.d/login`
   by deleting the lines (or fixing) you have added.

   ```
   vim /mnt/etc/pam.d/login
   ```

   (or whatever editor you prefer).
4. Reboot back into your system. Login should work normally.